# C# loop through array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array that contains 2 elements and each element can contain one or more `object` with two properties: `Id` -> (`string`) and `Names` -> (`List<string>`).

You'll probably understand better by taking a look at the following image:
[image]

How can I loop through the elements of the second object and get the `Id` and `Names` properties for each of them?

This is how I've tried to implement it, but doesn't work:

```
foreach (var elem in classArray[1].GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var id = elem.Id;
    var name = elem.Names;
}
```

This is the `Classification` class:

```
public class Classification
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

This is my code:

```
    List<object> classCollection = new List<object>();
    dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < response.Count; i++)
    {
        var classObj = response[i].element_classifications;
        var className = new List<string>();
        List<Classification> classList = new List<Classification>();

        for (int k = 0; k < classObj.Count; k++)
        {
            var classification = classObj[k].classifications;
            for (int j = 0; j < classification.Count; j++)
            {
                className.Add(classification[j].name.Value);
            }
            classList.Add(new Classification { Id = classObj[k].id.Value, Names = className });
        }
        classCollection.Add(classList);
    }
    var classArray = classCollection.ToArray();
```

Comment: Do you mean they can be *any* object, or they are always of type `ExcelSDRAddIn.UserControlSDR.Classification`?

Comment: They are always of that type

Comment: Why are you using `object[]` then if the items are all of the same type?  Using a strongly-typed collection will make life a lot easier.

Comment: I updated my question with my code ... It would help me a lot if you can tell me how to use a strongly-typed collection in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the objects to the appropriate class:

```
foreach (var elem in ((IEnumerable)classArray[1]).Cast<ExcelSDRAddIn.UserControlSDR.Classification>())
{
    var id = elem.Id;
    var name = elem.Names;
}
```

Comment: This returns me the following errors: `cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'`  and `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Cast<TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @Valip - you may need to also cast `classArray[1]`, like so: `((IEnumerable)classArray[1]).Cast<ExcelSDRAddIn.UserControlSDR.Classification>()`

Comment: It says that `Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Comment: It works if I initialize `classCollection` as follows: `List<ExcelSDRAddIn.UserControlSDR.Classification[]> classCollection = new List<ExcelSDRAddIn.UserControlSDR.Classification[]>();`

Comment: You would cast it to `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, not `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`. But you figured it out so hurray!

Answer (score 0):

If the object is always the same

```
foreach(ExcelSDRAddIn.UserControlSDR.Classification variableName in classArray[i])
```

Or you can use dynamic or var

```
dynamic v = classArray[i].Id;
dynamic name = classArray[i].Names;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your image, it looks like this would work:

```
foreach(var item in classArray[1])
{
    var typedItem = (ExcelSDRAddIn.UserControlSDR.Classification) item;

    Console.WriteLine($"Id {typedItem.Id} has names:");

    for (int i = 0; i < typedItem.Names.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" - {typedItem.Names[i]}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this too, but it returns `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: sorry, I missed that your array is of type `object` I updated my answer

Comment: @Valip is there some reason your array is not strongly typed to start with? Why is it not defined as: `ExcelSDRAddIn.UserControlSDR.Classification[] classArray;`

Comment: There is no reason my array is not strongly typed ... I just didn't know how to make it strongly typed. I updated the question with my code.